# Iterating over maps in List and matching value in Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, iteration, maps

please help with code to print value of key c by comparing key value of a and b

the output should be 29

```dart
int a = 3;
int b = 6;

List nums = [
  {'a': 1, 'b': 6, 'c': 9},
  {'a': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': 10},
  {'a': 3, 'b': 8, 'c': 19},
  {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 29},
  {'a': 2, 'b': 7, 'c': 39},
  {'a': 2, 'b': 8, 'c': 49},
];
```

Comment: `nums.where((m) => m['a'] == a && m['b'] == b).map((m) => m['c'])`

Answer (score 3):

As per https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/Iterable/where.html

```
    void main() {
      
      int a = 3;
    int b = 6;
    
    List nums = [
      {'a': 1, 'b': 6, 'c': 9},
      {'a': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': 10},
      {'a': 3, 'b': 8, 'c': 19},
      {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 29},
      {'a': 2, 'b': 7, 'c': 39},
      {'a': 2, 'b': 8, 'c': 49},
    ];
      
      
     
        print(nums.where((m) => m['a'] == a && m['b'] == b));

print(nums.where((m) => m['a'] == a && m['b'] == b).elementAt(0)['c']);
     
    }
```

the output will be

```
({a: 3, b: 6, c: 29})

29
```

Comment: not sure why you were downvoted, because it should be clear from here how to extract `c` from this result. In any case, I would suggest to improve your answer to only print `c` and not the entire object. There's also a small mistake in that you check on `== 3` instead of the actual variable like `== a`

Comment: Thanks @IvoBeckers for the review . Corrected the variable check instead of static check. I thought may be someone needs to understand how this whole code is working that's why printed object as well as the final 29 desired output.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will output 29.

```dart
main(){
  int a = 3;
  int b = 6;

  List nums = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 6, 'c': 9},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': 10},
    {'a': 3, 'b': 8, 'c': 19},
    {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 29},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 7, 'c': 39},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 8, 'c': 49},
  ];

  for(var item in nums){
    if(item['a'] == a && item['b'] == b){
      print(item['c']); // => 29
    }
  }
}
```